# Screen command in shell scripting

Tags: gnu-screen

I am a newbie in shell scripting and want to use the screen command to automate the below scenario:

1. Create a screen `session1` and execute a shell `script1`
2. create another screen `session2` and execute another shell `script2`, and if this result is success then go to screen `session1` and resume the `script1` there by pressing enter.

Is this possible using screen? please help with your suggestions how this can be done.

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible, but I've no idea why you'd want to do it that way.

It all depends whether this is an attempt to automate existing scripts, or if this something you've written from scratch - or the architecture of a new product entirely?

If it's the former, I'd say it'd be easier to edit the existing scripts (are you sure they're actually scripts?) to not wait like that, or integrate the logic from one into the other.

If it's the latter, then you're doing it wrong, and should be using some other mechanism of IPC (Inter-Process communication) that doesn't involve keypresses.

Comment: Thanks Tom for answering the question, for me the case I is there where I have the existing scripts. But I can't change the logic therein since script1 has to wait until the second script gets executed...can this be done using screen or should I search more on this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `screen -X stuff '\n'` to send a line feed to a running screen session.

I'd write a wrapper script that starts `script2`and sends a line feed to `session1` if the script terminates successfully:

```
#!/bin/bash
./script2 && screen -S session1 -X stuff '\n'
```

The follwing two commands would now do what you want:

```
screen -S session1 -d -m ./script1
screen -S session2 ./wrapper
```

Comment: I tried this but how can I be sure that the line feed was received by script1 or may be how can I go and check whats going on on session1 i.e. script1 works as expected and is proceeding further after line feed

Comment: You can attach to your screen session at any time: `screen -r session1`. Also, don't forget `man screen`.

Comment: I tried the command "screen -S session1 -d -m ./script1" but it doesn't add the screen and gives "cannot exec "session1" No such file or directory.However, if I tried adding screen manually with screen command it works.

Comment: I have version `4.01.00devel (GNU) 2-May-06` of the screen utility. I can't help you any more than that. I'm afraid you need to do some basic troubleshooting yourself...